# How to maintain the sender reputation after the IP warm up

Tags: marketing-cloud, deliverability

Is there a recommended weekly or monthly number of email send out to maintain the IP after IP warm up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should always aim at warming up towards your target volume, which you can maintain post-warmup. So keeping the weekly sends should not deviate a lot from your weekly target volume.

You should be OK having 1-2 weeks with lower volumes, but then you would want to go back to the target volume.

Going through more than 4 weeks with low volume, will result in ISPs seeing this as your new target volume. If this should happen, you will be able to increase back to your original target, but you must not exceed the increase of max double the previous week's volume.

This time of year is especially bad for significant volume increases, as ISPs are on high alert with added capacity to accommodate added load for holiday emails.

Comment: Thank you! My monthly weekly volume after the IP warm up will be approx 50 000, but there will be months when I will need to send even 400 000 (newsletter/special emails). I plan to finish IP warm up with 400 000 on the 8th week of Ip warm up. I wonder if ending the warm up with 400 000 and then sending only 50 000 in next month will have bad impact on the sender reputation? I saw that SF recommends to send at least 100 000 monthly after the IP warm up process to keep the IP warmed.